# How to add scope in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

Im looking into this project

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-docs-code-dotnet/tree/main/web-api#2-add-scopes

The above link suggests to add a scope, but doesnt list where the scope should be added?

I searched around and noticed Roles have been removed (if thats the same thing) but considering im using the default code supplied in that project (actually some may say its different as my code is for Web Core API and not minimal API), i cant get it to run.

I get a 401 and underlying error is

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope=
```

**Edit:**

I eventually found a section

App Registration > Expose an API > Add a scope

Following this i added the permission under API Permission and have green ticks under the status column but the same error above remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered one **Web API** in my Azure AD tenant as mentioned in that project like below:

[image]

Now, I added Application ID URI by clicking on **`Set`** in **Expose an API** tab like below:

[image]

To add scope, you need to click on **`Add a scope`** option and fill the details like below:

[image]

After adding scope, it will be displayed under **Scopes defined by this API** like below:

[image]

I cloned the same project and modified *./appsettings.json* file with **`ClientId`** and **`TenantId`** values like below:

```json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "f736a78c-7493-468a-a572-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxx",
    "Scopes": "Forecast.Read"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When I ran the project with **`dotnet run`** command, I got below response:

[image]

When I send an **authenticated request** to the web API via Postman by including bearer token, I got response successfully like below:

```http
GET https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]